# Drop duplicates for rows with interchangeable name values (Pandas, Python)

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I have a DataFrame of form

```
person1, person2, ..., someMetric
John, Steve, ..., 20
Peter, Larry, ..., 12
Steve, John, ..., 20
```

Rows 0 and 2 are interchangeable duplicates, so I'd want to drop the last row. I can't figure out how to do this in Pandas.

Thanks!

Comment: Are possible duplicates determined by only person1 and person2 , or are other columns involved?

Comment: Yes, person1 and person2 are unique identifiers. There are other columns, but the important relationship is between the two people.

Comment: Would you still remove the last row if its `someMetric` is some number other than `20`? Also, what if the last row were an exact duplicate of the first row, do we still remove it?

Comment: Yes, for all pairs of rows R1 and R2, where R1.person1 = R2.person2 AND R1.person2 = R2.person1 I want to drop R2

Comment: I've already dropped all exact duplicates

Comment: person1 and person2 can never be equal by nature of the way the dataset is generated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

an approach in pandas

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
{'person2':  {0: 'Steve', 1: 'Larry', 2: 'John', 3: 'Parker', 4: 'Peter'}, 
'person1': {0: 'John', 1: 'Peter', 2: 'Steve', 3: 'Peter', 4: 'Larry'}, 
'someMetric': {0: 20, 1: 13, 2: 19, 3: 5, 4: 7}})


print(df)
  person1 person2 someMetric
0    John   Steve         20
1   Peter   Larry         13
2   Steve    John         19
3   Peter  Parker          5
4   Larry   Peter          7


df['ordered-name'] = df.apply(lambda x: '-'.join(sorted([x['person1'],x['person2']])),axis=1)
df = df.drop_duplicates(['ordered-name'])
df.drop(['ordered-name'], axis=1, inplace=True)
print df
```

which gives:

```
  person1 person2  someMetric
0    John   Steve          20
1   Peter   Larry          13
3   Peter  Parker           5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a NumPy based solution  -

```
df[~(np.triu(df.person1.values[:,None] == df.person2.values)).any(0)]
```

Sample run -

```
In [123]: df
Out[123]: 
  person1 person2 someMetric
0    John   Steve         20
1   Peter   Larry         13
2   Steve    John         19
3   Peter  Parker          5
4   Larry   Peter          7

In [124]: df[~(np.triu(df.person1.values[:,None] == df.person2.values)).any(0)]
Out[124]: 
  person1 person2 someMetric
0    John   Steve         20
1   Peter   Larry         13
3   Peter  Parker          5
```